# Hidden list as template - Include content and deploy on new site

Tags: restore, list-template

There is a list which I am trying to take a backup and restore it on my local environment.

The list is hidden by default. I am uploading the template on new site but when I click on add an app button it doesn't come up.

Therefore, I wasn't able to restore it.

I found a solution to add it with feature id like on below

```
http://siteurl/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId={FEATUREID}&ListTemplate=100
```

It didn't work too, It restores the list but doesn't restore the content.

Is there any way to take backup and restore it ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to save again the list as template with its content.

...../_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx?List={listGuid}

Check the checkbox "include content".